# Every subset of discrete space is open and closed.

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

Had a look at the solutions and their answer is different. Was wondering if my attempt works and would love some feedback? Thank you in advance!

- **Question:**

Let $X$ be a non-empty set equipped with the discrete metric. Prove that every subset $Y$ of $X$ is both open and closed.

- **My attempt:**

Let $r = 2$

Since we are dealing with the discrete metric, $∀a,b∈X, d(a,b)≤1$

$⇒ B(y,2) = \{z∈X|d(y,z)≤1<r = 2\}$ and therefore $∃r>0$ such that $B(y,r)⊆X$

Therefore any subset $Y$ is open $⇒$ any subset $X\setminus Y$ is closed. Therefore any subset $Y⊆X$ is both open and closed.

Comment: In the future make sure to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your posts.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Solution verification tag is not for verifying your solutions, but particular steps of confusion in your solution. That's why I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that in a discrete metric space, every subset is both open and closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194201/show-that-in-a-discrete-metric-space-every-subset-is-both-open-and-closed)

Comment: It gives me an answer but I'm still unsure of whether my proof is correct, since it goes in a very different route from most solutions I can find, where they set r<1 whereas I am attempting it by setting r>1. This is the step in particular that I am confused about.

Comment: Well, $\{z\in X : d(y, z) \leq 1 < r = 2\}$ while not incorrect, you rarely write things like that and I want to point out there might be some confusion on your part on how to write sets. Your solution is wrong but if you take $B(y, 1/2) = \{y\}$ then you'll be able to show that $Y$ is open.

Comment: $B(y, 2) = X$ so its rarely contained in $Y\subseteq X$ unless $Y = X$

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the help

Comment: @Jakobian just revisited this question and realised I had copied the definition of an open set wrong hence the confusion. Your answer helped me realise this so thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem. You can click on "close" and choose the question this is a duplicate of if you refused the suggested close vote for a duplicate.